# Does my ARIMA Model Fail because of the non stationary data?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality, trend

I am trying to create an ARIMA model which allows to extrapolate a voltage curve of a sensor battery into the future. Is this a possible application scenario at all?

I have four different voltage waveforms from two different sensors (Hourly measured values) that I want to use to train the model (I have inflated each waveform to 1000 data points so that all waveforms contain the same data points):

[image: Training data set]

Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test over Trainings set:

```
1. ADF : -2.3325211837089252
2. P-Value : 0.16169362186896774
3. Num Of Lags : 0
4. Num Of Observations Used For ADF Regression and Critical Values Claculation : 3999
pandCritical Values : 
    1% : -3.431986284700283
    5% : -2.862263021072379
    10% : -2.5671548718243575
```

P-Value of 0.16 => the data set is not stationary

```
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df_train['rm_data_BatV'])
decomposition.plot()
```

[image: seasonal_decompose]

How should we assess the trend here?
From my point of view, the individual curves show a downward trend, but the complete data set over time does not show a trend?

The seasonal component between 0.001 and - 0.001 is negligible?

Or would the plot have to be set with period=1000, since voltage curve includes 1000 data points?

```
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df_train['rm_data_BatV'], period=1000)
decomposition.plot()
```

[image]

Does the data set now have a trend component and a seasonal component?
Can these be eliminated?

```
plot_acf(df_train['rm_data_BatV'])
plot_pacf(df_train['rm_data_BatV'])
```

[image: ACF-PCF-Plot]

Is it because of this high autocorellation that the ARIMA model does not work?

```
pmas = pma.auto_arima(df_train['rm_data_BatV'])
pmas.summary()
```

AutoARIMA gives me (0,1,0)

```
sarimax = SARIMAX(df_train['rm_data_BatV'], order=(0, 1, 0))
result = sarimax.fit()
result.summary()

predict_train = result.predict(start=df_train.index[0])
```

Result about the Train data set:

[image: result Test data]

```
model = SARIMAX(df_test[5:]['rm_data_BatV'],  order=(0, 1, 0))
result_new = model.filter(result.params)
predict_test = result_new.predict(start=df_test.index[6])
predict_test_future = result_new.forecast(steps=24 * 7)
```

Result about the test data:

[image: Result test data]

I hope someone can tell me where the problem is and why it is not working. Is it the data, are they prepared incorrectly?
Is the ARIMA model wrong here?
Is ARIMA not meant for this kind of use cases and why?
Can the ARIMA model be trained on and map only single curves?

I am grateful for any feedback.

Comment: There's way, way, way too much information here and too many questions.  Please edit this down to a single answerable question.  (In any case, my proposed short answer would be that (S)ARIMA is not a suitable model for most of the waveforms you present, which suggests that you ought to focus on your *objectives* rather than on this particular *procedure* that isn't working out for achieving those objectives.)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! in general, the answer is enough for me for what reason ARIMA models are not suitable for this type of voltage curves (picture one). Do you have an answer to this question?

Comment: If your waveforms tend, repeatedly, to look like these examples, then they exhibit such radically different behaviors at various times as to suggest they cannot be accurately described by any *stationary* process, which by definition has comparable statistical characteristics at every time.  It also doesn't look like any amount of differencing would improve that.  Understand that this is merely an impression gleaned from trying to interpret your graphs, but it suggests you might be better off looking for a different way to model your situation rather than forcing ARIMA to fit it.

Comment: Thank you for your assessment, this was exactly my guess! Thank you for taking the time. can you maybe still tell me if LSTM is suitable for this problem?